# Microsoft DNS : SRV record for sub-domain without creating a new zone

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, internal-dns, windows-dns

On Microsoft DNS server (Windows Server 2012): We have a DNS Zone for `domain.com`

We need to create the following SRV record:
`_xmpp-server._tcp.child.domain.com` => target is = `host.domain.com`

Can we create SRV records for `child.domain.com` without having to create a new DNS zone for "child" domain?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I don't own DNS in my organization and can't try it. I want to raise a request to have them do it, but want to confirm if my request is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the domain `child.domain.com` nowhere delegated from authoritative servers for the domain `domain.com`. And separate zone for the domain `child.domain.com` not present, the SRV record `_xmpp-server._tcp.child.domain.com` can be created without problems in the domain zone `domain.com`.

Comment: Are you sure I can create SRV records for child.domain.com in the domain.com zone? I know we do this on Route 53 or other DNS services, but on a Windows DNS the UI for creating new SRV record does not allow me to change the domain value

Comment: [@HashSRVDNS](http://serverfault.com/users/395207/hashsrvdns) in Windows GUI simple insert `_xmpp-server._tcp.child` in hostname field - it will autocreate all nessesary folders for you.